# Recommended practice for using import_module in django >= 1.8

Tags: django, django-1.8, deprecation-warning

In one of my django tests, I use `django.utils.importlib.import_module` similarly to how it is used [here](http://blog.mathandpencil.com/unit-testing-best-practices-in-django/).

On upgrading to django 1.8, I get a deprecation warning

```
test_views.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module
```

Is the recommended practice now to use `import_module` from `importlib` in the standard library (which seems to work fine)? Or is the recommended practice to avoid using `import_module` entirely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Based on the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#django-utils-dictconfig-django-utils-importlib) (found by looking at the [django deprecation timeline for 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9) and following the link), your first suggestion seems to be correct: developers should use the standard [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) that is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `django.utils.importlib.import_module` is effectively the same thing as `importlib.import_module`. As long as you're not targeting a version of Python before 2.7, it is okay to just use `importlib.import_module`.

Comment: it has problems with Python3 version < 3.4, because Django tries to use find_spec but find_spec was added only in 3.4.